Ubuntu 22.04: QSystemTrayIcon needs reboot to display after Gnome Shell Extension App Indicators is installed
Using Qt Framework on Ubuntu 22.04. The UI consists of a QSystemTrayIcon which is dependent on the installation of the App Indicator Gnome Shell Extension:
$ sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-appindicator

QSystemTrayIcon can be seen but it requires a logout/login after installing gnome-shell-extension-appindicator. Is there a way to have gnome-shell-extension-appindicator take effect enabling the QSystemTrayIcon to display without having to logout and login back in?

If you install the AppIndicator extension from your package manager, you will have to logout and login for it to be loaded.
If you install it from extensions.gnome.org (i.e. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/) then it should be loaded immediately.
